# Symfony 6 dependency injection outside of controller

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired, symfony6

Hello i'm trying to use dependency injection outside of controller but i always have an error message that say : Too few arguments to function (...), 0 passed in (...) and exactly 1 expected.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Response;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class TestResponse
{
  public function __construct(private LoggerInterface $logger)
  {}
}
```

Normally with autowiring it sould work but here no ...
I don't understand why

i've try to inject dependency as parameter like in controllers but this not working
The autowiring is enabled
I think is natively possible like in controllers, without adding new package to do that

Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !
i post here to help on the same problem

Before my controller is like that : This block trigger the error i said before

```
  #[Route('/test', name: 'test', methods: ['GET'])]
  public function test(): JsonResponse
  {
    $response = new TestResponse();
    return new JsonResponse([]);
  }
```

I forget how to implement service : This is the good way how to implement this

```
  #[Route('/test', name: 'test', methods: ['GET'])]
  public function test(TestResponse $response): JsonResponse
  {
    // $response->...
    return new JsonResponse([]);
  }
```